# EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, ado.net

I can't seem to avoid this error of "EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code" in my view on "@foreach(var item in Model)". So I started from scratch and created a new project -> ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application.
After this I was attempting to access my database by utilizing ADO.NET and LINQ, so I added the model class of "Case.cs"

Case.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CustomerService.Models
{
    public class Case
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Creator { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CaseLead { get; set; }
        public string CaseType { get; set; }
        public string CaseSubType1 { get; set; }
        public string CaseSubType2 { get; set; }
        public string CaseStatus { get; set; }
        public string CaseTitle { get; set; }
        public string CaseDescription { get; set; }
        public string CaseContact { get; set; }
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string LocationID { get; set; }
        public string SystemID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I added the DbContext as "CSdb.cs"

CSdb.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CustomerService.Models
{
    public class CSdb : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Case> Cases { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I added a controller named "CaseController.cs"

CaseController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CustomerService.Models;

namespace CustomerService.Controllers
{
    public class CaseController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Case/

        CSdb db = new CSdb();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = db.Cases;

            return View(model);
        }

    }
}
```

Last, I added the index view for CaseController.cs named "Index.cshtml"

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomerService.Models.Case>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Creator
            </th>
            <th>
                CreatedDate
            </th>
            <th>
                CaseLead
            </th>
            <th>
                CaseType
            </th>
            <th>
                CaseSubType1
            </th>
            <th>
                CaseSubType2
            </th>
            <th>
                CaseStatus
            </th>
            <th>
                CaseTitle
            </th>
            <th>
                CaseDescription
            </th>
            <th>
                CaseContact
            </th>
            <th>
                CustomerID
            </th>
            <th>
                LocationID
            </th>
            <th>
                SystemID
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Creator)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseLead)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseSubType1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseSubType2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseStatus)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseTitle)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseDescription)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseContact)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SystemID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
```

Now when I debug this and navigate to this view, I get the error of "EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code - An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details" and this message is pointing at "@foreach(var item in Model) {" in my index view for Case. Also, I'm attempting to use Code First, so I do not have the table created yet, but I have hit the Build Solution.

Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: well try to change your controller's code to `var model = db.Cases.ToList();` and you'll see that your exception will be raised there... if you don't have any db yet. Exception comes when you try to get data from db.

Comment: Please, show an inner exception.

Comment: So I added the .ToList() and the exception did raise in my controller, but now should I manually create my table in my db? I thought 'Code first' would automatically create this table from my model? I have my connection string pointing at a local db. 'code'  <add name="CSdb" connectionString="Data Source=SAN3716\LOCAL;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />'code'

Comment: First of all, what version of EF are you using? Please also read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.aspx and see if that clears it up.

Comment: I'm kind of a noob at this, but I'm not sure on how to find the inner exception. But EF is v4.0.30319 and I didn't get far with the article, but thanks for providing the link.

Comment: So I think I may no what the problem is. My InnerException says "{"Invalid object name 'dbo.Cases'."}"    Now, I'm pretty sure I do not have permission to write to the 'dbo' schema and I'm suppose to write to a 'cs.' schema instead. If anyone knows of an article or a video that explains how to use code first to change the schema from 'dbo.' to 'xxxx.' instead that would be very useful.